# How to set data source of NSComboBox to plist?

Tags: objective-c, macos, plist, nscombobox

I have a plist called `People.plist` and I'm trying to populate an `NSComboBox` called `nameBox`. I can't find anything in the documentation that says how to do this or if it's even possible. I assume this is easy, but I can't seem to find anything anywhere that works.

How do I populate an NSComboBox using a plist?

This is what I have, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.nameBox.delegate = self;
    [_nameBox setUsesDataSource:NO];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"People" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSMutableArray *contents = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
    for (int i = 0; i < [contents count]; i++){
        [_nameBox addItemWithObjectValue:[[contents objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Name"]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Which part is the problem? Reading the plist or populating the combobox? What did you try?

Comment: What is the value of `contents`?